# In in-line CSS syntax. How do I place an image called image.jpg in absolute position of 10 pixels to the left and 10 pixels to the top

Tags: css, syntax, helper

In in-line CSS syntax for placing an image called image.jpg in absolute position of 10 pixels to the left and 10 pixels to the top.

I have no idea where to start. I am very new to this.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself preferably in a Stack Snippet. See [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) Please read the documentation about what a good SO question needs: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Write this :

```
<img  style="position: absolute;top:10px;left:10px" src="image.jpg" alt="image">
```